Certificates SAN values when using TCP Load Balancer
I need some advices or best practices advices about SAN values on certificates.
Here's the context :
We got 2 servers that host the same application (clustered app on active-active mode). On top, we got an external TCP Load Balancer that only acts like a TCP relay to one or another server.
Typical scenario is :
user will request the Load Balancer and LoadBalancer will transmit request to one or another server (round robin configuration)

Load Balancer IP is 10.10.10.1 and its name lb.mydomain.net

Server 1 IP for user is 10.10.11.1 and its FQDN is server1.mydomain.net

Server 1 IP for admin is 10.10.11.2 and its FQDN is server1-admin.mydomain.net

Server 2 IP for user is 10.10.11.3 and its FQDN is server2.mydomain.net

Server 2 IP for admin is 10.10.11.4 and its FQDN is server2-admin.mydomain.net


As usual, we set up SSL certificate on our hosts/apps but in that case i'm not sure about which configuration will cover this :
Scenario 1 : create a certificate with lb.mydomain.net as CN and SAN values as : server1.mydomain.net, server1-admin.mydomain.net , server2.mydomain.net and server2-admin.mydomain.net
Scenario 2 : create the same certificate but adding all IPs. However, it seems to be not very secure according to this article
What should be the best practice ?
Thanks a lot !

Never heard of 2. No one does that. Where did you get that?

Some old way of working here, probably in case of DNS failure I guess, but to me it's not secure

RFC 5280 allows for IP addresses, however, IP addresses instead of names should be an exception, as it is everywhere else.  There may be an internal/external name conflict. You may want to check why it is like this for impact.

If your load balancer supports TLS termination (offload), then load balancer needs only one name in its certificate: lb.mydomain.net. Since load balancer acts as an abstraction layer, individual node names are not visible to clients, so they are not required to be presented in a LB's certificate. Individual NLB nodes should have a certificate that contains only server name in server certificate:

When client connects to your application, two separate connections (and TLS sessions) are established:

Between client and NLB. Everything behind NLB is not really visible to client.
Between NLB and backend node. Backend nodes have no idea that there is anything in front of NLB.

If your NLB does not support TLS termination, then it acts as a transparent bridge and simply relay traffic between client, then every node must have a certificate with lb.mydomain.net name in SAN certificate. Load balancer will be completely transparent to all, clients and NLB nodes. This configuration is less common and suitable for completely stateless applications, or applications that replicate internal (including session) state between each other.
Speaking about scenario 2, then you should not use it at all. Connecting to applications by IP never was a good idea if you have working DNS. An idea to use IP as a backup should your DNS fail: TLS warnings or errors is your lesser problem. Use only DNS names to connect your network applications. Then you put only DNS names in certificates. Sticking to IPs kills the purpose of DNS and make IP addressing even more complicated, because IP is hardcoded somewhere on a client and you won't be able to change server IP without reconfiguring clients.

Hi ! Thanks for this amazing explanation. In my case my LB is able to support ssl offloading but it seems no one already give a try in my company so i'll be the first. If i understand well, the LB will handle the ciffered traffic instead of any NLB right ? About scenario 2 as mentionned in another comment, people here used to add IP as SAN values (we got our own internal PKI also, nothing public or external)


right, NLB will terminate TLS on both sides and can read the traffic. It is often the case and needed for high-level (OSI 4+ layer) load balancers for better effectiveness and intelligence. 2) while IPs are supported, I don't recommend to use them explicitly from practical and administration standpoint. Like I said, DNS failures are rare, but if they happen, you have much bigger problems than invalid name in certificate.


After some tests, I finally set one certificate per node that embbed the LB FQDN as SAN.
The reason is, as my application forward requests to open SSH/RDP session then, i can't use SSL offloading on my TCP LB (i made some test on another app and it works great for http/https and also ssl)
Huge thanks @Crypt32 & @GregAskew for those precious explanations !
